# Using arrays and strings together

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I'm trying to create an array that contains some user inputted names, and then associate those names with letter grades from tests (ex: A, B, C, D, F). My question is, how would I use an array to accept the user inputted names?

EDIT:

Sorry this is a bit long, I don't know what part to put that would help out. Totally new to C++ and I can't seem to find anything online regarding the matter, lol.

Here is some code. This program currently asks the user for test scores, then displays and drops the lowest test score, and finally, calculates the average of the scores without the lowest one. The end goal is to ask the user for 5 students names, and 4 scores for each student, then dropping the lowest score for each student and calculating the averages of ALL scores inputted regardless of student.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getScore(int &);
int findLowest(int [], int);
void calcAverage(int [], int);

int main () {

const int NUM_SCORES = 5;
int scores[NUM_SCORES];

cout << "Welcome to test averages." << endl;
cout << "Please enter scores for " << NUM_SCORES << " students." << endl;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; i++) {
    getScore(scores[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; i++) {
    cout << "Score " << (i + 1) << ": " << scores[i] << endl;
}

cout << endl;
cout << "The lowest of these scores is " << findLowest(scores, NUM_SCORES) << endl;

calcAverage(scores, NUM_SCORES);

return 0;
}

void getScore(int & s) {

s = -1;
cout << "Please enter a test score: ";
cin >> s;

while (s < 0 || s > 100) {
    cout << "Score range must be from 0-100" << endl;
    cout << "Please re-enter a score: ";
    cin >> s;
}
}

int findLowest(int theArray [], int theArraySize) {

int lowest = theArray[0];

for (int i = 1; i < theArraySize; i++) {

    if (theArray[i] < lowest) {
        lowest = theArray[i];
    }
}

return lowest;
}

void calcAverage(int theArray [], int theArraySize) {

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < theArraySize; i++) {
    sum += theArray[i];
}

double average = (sum - findLowest(theArray, theArraySize)) / (theArraySize - 1.0);
cout << "The average is " << average << endl;

}
```

Comment: An array of strings? Or if you don't want a fixed-size array use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (my recommendation).

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I'd love to post an answer, but can you post what code you have.  Or in lieu of or in addition to that a precise example of your input files

Comment: In the average calculation, surely you meant `0.0` rather than `1.0` ? the average of 1,2,3 is (1+2+3)/3, not (1+2+3)/(3-1)

Comment: @M.M The calcAverage drops the lowest number entered by the user, so you have to drop the empty entry on the array or else it will screw up the average calculation.

Comment: OK, so it really means the average of the other numbers excluding the lowest one. Would be good if that were mentioned in the code comments somewhere :)

Comment: Use `std::map`. That's an associative array provided by the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getline` from `#include <string>`

```
std::string names[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    getline(std::cin, names[i]);
}
```